# Технология для организации видео конференции на сайте

Tags: flash, видео

Вообщем на чем лучше делать для того что на сайте организовать трансляцию с 2+ веб камер с возможностью пассивного подключения еще юзеров, т.е. они не транслируются, просто подключаются и слушают, кроме флеша есть другие варианты?
Сайт предполагает высокие нагрузки

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 + JavaScript, Silverlight, Java апплеты или написать свой плагин :)
А чем флеш не устраивает? Есть p2p чтобы снижать нагрузку.

Answer (score 0):

[dimdim](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dimdim/):

> Dimdim - продукт с открытым исходным кодом для веб-конференций с такими функциями, как  совместного использования приложения, рабочего стола и презентация аудио-видео потока и чат. Нет требуется установка - все функции доступны через веб-браузер.

[red5chat](http://www.red5chat.com/.):

> Полнофункциональный веб-чат.

[silverlightvideochat](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/):

> Проект модулей аудио-видео конференций.